# how to prevent Webview from using cookies in android

Tags: android, caching, cookies, webview

i have 2  links , once i set the first on my webview even if i load the second one i will still see the first one . even after restart application .

i is also will happen in pc browser with these links unless i delete cookies .

i have try many things but none of them work .

how can i load url and make sure that he will not use cookies and load all data from scratch ?

i have try this

```
 mWebView.getSettings().setCacheMode(WebSettings.LOAD_NO_CACHE);
```

and this

```
CookieManager.getInstance().setAcceptCookie(false);
```

which opened the phone browser and ignored my webview .

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Remove the old cookie data

```
CookieSyncManager.createInstance(this);
CookieManager cookieManager = CookieManager.getInstance();
cookieManager.removeAllCookie();
cookieManager.setAcceptCookie(false)
```

And try to handle override of webview url

```
mWebView.setWebViewClient(new WebViewClient() {  
      @Override  
      public boolean shouldOverrideUrlLoading(WebView view, String url)  
      {  

        return false;  
      }  
    });
```

Comment: cookieManager.removeAllCookie();
cookieManager.setAcceptCookie(false) were removed because made issues with my user agent .

Comment: cookieManager.setAcceptCookie(false)  use this make application runnig very slow. do you have any idea?